# Response time benchmarks for Salesforce APIs

Tags: api, performance

For all the various APIs exposed by Salesforce like Bulk, Composite etc. each have their own developer guides which include like how to use them, and various limits applicable to them.

But I didn't find any published response time benchmarks. For eg: in Bulk API, if Insert operation is performed for Contact object, for an batch size of XXXX (with say XX fields) what is the average/least time taken for batch to complete.

Help out if I have missed discovering the right documentation.

Comment: i don't believe this is documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to know, because (a) customizations can increase the time, and (b) system load does have some impact.

The minimal amount of time for a pristine org is about 1ms per record (1/1,000th of a second), and can easily be over 10,000ms per record.

If you're really curious, try a load late at night and one at noon. That should give you theoretical minimums and maximums for your org.